# How to scrape tens of thousands urls every night using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-splash, scrapy-pipeline

I am using scrapy to scrape some big brands to import the sale data for my site. Currently I am using

```
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 1.5

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16

CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16
```

I am using Item loader to specify css/xpath rules and Pipeline to write the data into csv. The data that I collect is original price, sale price, colour, sizes, name, image url and brand.

I have written the spider for only one merchant who has around 10k urls and it takes me about 4 hours.

My question is, does 4 hours sounds alright for 10k urls or it should be faster than that. If so, what else do I need to do to speed it up.

I am using only one SPLASH instance locally to test. But in production I am planning to use 3 SPLASH instances.

Now the main issue, I have about 125 merchants and on avg 10k product for each. couple of them has more than 150k urls to scrape.

I need to scrape all their data every night to update my site. 
Since my single spider takes 4 hours to scrape 10k urls, I am wondering if it is even valid dream to achieve 125 x 10k urls every night

I will really appreciate your experienced input to my problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about a specific programming problem. It relates to performance on an system architectural level.

Comment: CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN doesn't apply if CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP is non-zero, so you may as well delete that.

Comment: use this one instead of scapy, https://github.com/buckyroberts/Spider

Comment: with due respect to @KlausD. where do you think I should ask this question? Stackoverflow is the place to share knowledge and help each other for problems. Or am I missing something? Thanks for your comment.

Comment: SO has a clear focus, much narrower than the scope you just decribed. To handle question that do not fit the scope of SO many sibling projects have been created.

Comment: Thanks, I will remember for future post.

Comment: For the record, I disagree with @KlausD.; this is a genuine and interesting computing problem.

Answer (score 5):

Your DOWNLOAD_DELAY is enforced per IP, so if there is only 1 IP, then 10,000 requests will take 15000 seconds (10,000 * 1.5). That is just over 4 hours. So yeah that's about right.

If you are scraping more than one site, then they will be different IP addresses, and so they should run more or less in parallel, so should still take 4 hours or so.

If you are scraping 125 sites, then you will probably hit a different bottleneck at some point.